# R : Error in linear regression model

Tags: r, regression

I have a 2 different data frames for which i would like to perform linear regression

I have written following code for it

```
mydir<- "/media/dev/Daten/Task1/subject1/t1"
#multiple subject paths should be given here
# read full paths
myfiles<- list.files(mydir,pattern = "regional_vol*",full.names=T)
# initialise the dataframe from first file 

df<- read.table( myfiles[1], header = F,row.names = NULL, skip = 3, nrows = 1,sep = "\t") 
# [-c(1:3),]
df
#read all the other files and update dataframe
#we read 4 lines to read the header correctly, then remove 3 
ans<- lapply(myfiles[-1], function(x){  read.table( x, header = F, skip = 3, nrows = 1,sep = "\t")       })
ans
#update dataframe
#[-c(1:3),]
lapply(ans, function(x){df<<-rbind(df,x)}  )
#this should be the required dataframe

uncorrect<- array(df)

# Linear regression of ICV extracted from global size FSL 
# Location where your icv is located
ICVdir <- "/media/dev/Daten/Task1/T1_Images"
#loding csv file from ICV
mycsv  <- list.files(ICVdir,pattern = "*.csv",full.names = T )
af<- read.csv(file = mycsv,header = TRUE)
ICV<- as.data.frame(af[,2],drop=FALSE)
#af[1,]
#we take into consideration second column  of csv
#finalcsv <-lapply(mycsv[-1],fudnction(x){read.csv(file="global_size_FSL")})
subj1<- as.data.frame(rep(0.824,each=304))

plot(df ~ subj1, data = df,
       xlab = "ICV value of each subject",
       ylab = "Original uncorrected volume",
       main="intercept calculation"
       )

fit <- lm(subj1 ~ df )
```

The data frame df has 304 values in following format

```
6433 6433     
1430 1430     
1941 1941     
3059 3059     
3932 3932     
6851 6851
```

and another data frame Subj1 has 304 values in following format

```
0.824     
0.824     
0.824      
0.824     
0.824
```

When i run my code i am incurring following error

```
Error in model.frame.default(formula = subj1 ~ df, drop.unused.levels = TRUE) : 
  invalid type (list) for variable 'subj1'
```

any suggestions why the data.frame values from variable subj1 are invalid

Comment: Seems like a StackOverflow question. Have you tried `str(subj1)`? That may provide some insights

Comment: @Jon, Yes i have tried it, it returned following values :      str(subj1) : 'data.frame': 304 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ rep(0.824, each = 304): num  0.824 0.824 0.824 0.824 0.824 0.824 0.824 0.824 0.824 0.824 ..

Comment: I think R expects a vector, not a data.frame. Did you try using `subj1 <- rep(0.824,each=304)` without turning it into a df?

Comment: @JarkoDubbeldam , Yes, I have tried it but the problem is with  other data frame  "df", how could i possibly convert data.frame "df" into an array?

Comment: If you go to the documentation for `model.matrix`, see if you can replicate the first example (they use trees data set) for your data. If you can't compute the model.frame or model.matrix, then @JarkoDubbeldam may be correct. You may in fact need to combind the two data frames together so that you are referencing only one data frame.

Comment: @JarkoDubbeldam , when i started using subj1 as an array instead of data frame i am getting following error : Error in model.frame.default(formula = subj1 ~ df, drop.unused.levels = TRUE) : 
  invalid type (list) for variable 'df'

Comment: Yep, `as.matrix(df)` should fix that.

Comment: @JarkoDubbeldam , as you can see the data in data frame df has 2 columns where as in Subj1 i have only one column, will that cause some problems in linear regression ?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, you are trying to give a data.frame as an independent variable. Try:

```
 fit <- lm(subj1 ~ ., data=df )
```

This will use all variables in the data frame, as long as `subj1` is the dependent variable's name, and not a data frame by itself.

If df has two columns which are the predictors, and subj1 is the predicted (dependent) variable, combing the two, give them proper column names, and create the model in the format above.

Something like:

```
data <- cbind(df, subj1)
names(data) <- c("var1", "var2", "subj1")
fit <- lm(subj1 ~ var1 + var2, data=df )
```

Edit: some pointers:

1. make sure you use a single data frame that holds **all** of your independent variables, and your dependent variable.
2. The number of rows should be equal.
3. If an independent variable in a constant, it has no variance for different values of the dependent variable, and so will have no meaning. If the dependent variable is a constant, there is no point for regressing - we can predict the value with 100% accuracy.

Comment: I would like to get slope of regression curve and the output of regression does not provide me an intercept : following is the output  : Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 1.948e-29 on 2 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:      0, Adjusted R-squared:  -150.5 
F-statistic:     0 on 301 and 2 DF,  p-value: 1

Warning message:
In summary.lm(fit) : essentially perfect fit: summary may be unreliable
>

Comment: That's because in the code you posted in the op, the response variable `subj1` is a constant, so the intercept in itself if a perfect predictor. You don't need a slope to predict `subj1`, because you know it just be looking at it.

Comment: following is the error that i am obtaining : Error in names(data) <- c("var1", "var2", "subj1") : 
  'names' attribute [3] must be the same length as the vector [2]

Comment: you must bind subj1 with the data frame. And @JarkoDubbeldam is right, it must not be constant, or there is no variance.